# Mvc Runtime error - The Role Manager feature has not been enabled

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, roles

I am trying to implement basic role management manually. When a user logs in if they are admin or not they are added to a role

I am getting this error:**Exception Details: System.Configuration.Provider.ProviderException: The Role Manager feature has not been enabled.**

This is the method that causes the error:

```
 public void addUserToRole(String user, String role)
        {
            if (!Roles.RoleExists(role))
                Roles.CreateRole(role);

            Roles.AddUserToRole(user, role);
        }
```

here is my web.config

```
 <profile defaultProvider="DefaultProfileProvider">
      <providers>
        <add name="DefaultProfileProvider" type="System.Web.Providers.DefaultProfileProvider, System.Web.Providers, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx" connectionStringName="DefaultConnection" applicationName="/" />
      </providers>
    </profile>
    <membership defaultProvider="DefaultMembershipProvider">
      <providers>
        <add name="DefaultMembershipProvider" type="System.Web.Providers.DefaultMembershipProvider, System.Web.Providers, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=xxxxxxxxxxxxx" connectionStringName="DefaultConnection" enablePasswordRetrieval="false" enablePasswordReset="true" requiresQuestionAndAnswer="false" requiresUniqueEmail="false" maxInvalidPasswordAttempts="5" minRequiredPasswordLength="6" minRequiredNonalphanumericCharacters="0" passwordAttemptWindow="10" applicationName="/" />
      </providers>
    </membership>
    <roleManager defaultProvider="DefaultRoleProvider">
      <providers>
        <add name="DefaultRoleProvider" type="System.Web.Providers.DefaultRoleProvider, System.Web.Providers, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=xxxxxxxxxxxxxx" connectionStringName="DefaultConnection" applicationName="/" />
      </providers>
    </roleManager>
    <sessionState mode="InProc" customProvider="DefaultSessionProvider">
      <providers>
        <add name="DefaultSessionProvider" type="System.Web.Providers.DefaultSessionStateProvider, System.Web.Providers, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=xxxxxxxxxxxx" connectionStringName="DefaultConnection" />
      </providers>
    </sessionState>
```

I've seen number of answers on google including adding different role  attributes in web.conf, so far no luck

can some one please help?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

By default the role manger is disabled, so you have to enable it explicitly:

```
<roleManager enabled="true" defaultProvider="DefaultRoleProvider">
```

Comment: Then I just get `Default Role Provider could not be found`.  (MVC 5)

Comment: If you're having this problem in an MVC 4 project, try this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17980288/3585500). Worked for me after I cut-n-pasted the whole block in.

Answer (score 6):

I tried this in MVC 5 and it worked:

```
  <system.web>
    <authentication mode="None" />
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5" />
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5" />
    <roleManager enabled="true" />
  </system.web>
```

After adding the "roleManager" line shown above to the web.config, I could add a new role and add a user to the role without any exception:

```
   if (!Roles.RoleExists(_role))
      Roles.CreateRole(_role);

   if (!Roles.IsUserInRole(_username, _role))
      Roles.AddUserToRole(_username, _role);
```

Comment: Yes this correct. In fact, OWIN handles the authentication so don't worry that there is no forms authentication any more.

Comment: I needed to add the `enabled="true"` clause to my `roleManager` element in my current project -- but I checked my previous project, and that did NOT have this clause.  Go figure.

Comment: I got the error: Unable to connect to SQL Server database.

Answer (score 1):

With your DefaultRoleProvider try this

```
   <roleManager defaultProvider="DefaultRoleProvider" enabled ="true">
```

Comment: DefaultRoleProvider Does not exist!