# ASP.Net, cannot access Security link

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, visual-studio-2012

I am running Visual Studio Express 2013 for Web on Windows 8 64bit and I following an MVC tutorial to access Web Site Administration Tool

http://mvc4beginner.com/Tutorial/Sign-in-Sign-up-Authentication-Authorization-Using-MVC-Membership-Provider.html

I finally figured out how to access Web Configuration Tool from here

[Visual Studio 2013 and ASP.NET Web Configuration Tool](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20541680/visual-studio-2013-and-asp-net-web-configuration-tool)

This is what I get (blacked-out current user name)

[image]

But when I click **Security** I get **error**

> There is a problem with your selected data store. This can be caused
>   by an invalid server name or credentials, or by insufficient
>   permission. It can also be caused by the role manager feature not
>   being enabled. Click the button below to be redirected to a page where
>   you can choose a new data store.
>
> The following message may help in diagnosing the problem:  Server
>   cannot access application directory
>   'C:\ASP\AuthenticationAuthorization\AuthenticationAuthorization\AuthenticationAuthorization.csproj\'.
>   The directory does not exist or is not accessible because of security
>   settings.

And I am researching how to enable role manager feature from here

[Mvc Runtime error - The Role Manager feature has not been enabled](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19329159/mvc-runtime-error-the-role-manager-feature-has-not-been-enabled)

But I cannot find `<roleManager enabled="true" defaultProvider="DefaultRoleProvider">` anywhere in the web.config

How do I troubleshoot this issue so I can access **Security** link? I can access **Application Configuration** and **Provider Configuration**.

EDIT

I click "Choose Data Store" and "Select a single provider for all site management data".

[image]

And when I click "Test" I get, even though the database I am connected to is MS SQL Server 2012

[image]

And when I click "Run the program without getting help" I get another error

> Could not establish a connection to the database.   If you have not
>   yet created the SQL Server database, exit the Web Site Administration
>   tool, use the aspnet_regsql command-line utility to create and
>   configure the database, and then return to this tool to set the
>   provider.

But I already ran aspnet_regsql and a database was created. I even reflected this in the web.config file,

```
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="DefaultConnection" connectionString="Data Source=10.10.10.11;  
                           Initial Catalog=aspnetdb;  
                           Persist Security Info=True;  
                           User ID=sem5;  
                           Password=Plaintext-Password" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
  </connectionStrings>
```