# .NET MVC 5/EF6 Roles

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework-6

Currently working on a small web app in MVC5 with EF6 and I receive this error:

```
An exception of type 'System.Configuration.Provider.ProviderException' occurred in System.Web.dll but was not handled in user code

Additional information: The Role Manager feature has not been enabled.
```

The code that triggers this error is as follows:

```
@if (Roles.IsUserInRole("Admin") || Roles.IsUserInRole("Standard"))
```

As far as I know, roleManager is not a thing in EF6 and MVC5, but back from Membership. I have seen many questions and solutions that refer back to EF5 or claim to be for EF6, while I thought Role Manager to be EF5.

How should I solve this error correctly, according to best practices in EF6/MVC5?

Comment: Look @ this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19329159/mvc-runtime-error-the-role-manager-feature-has-not-been-enabled

Comment: Amazing! It does work!
And how should I look at EF6? Is roleManager part of Identity, or..?

Comment: Yes `RoleManager<T>`

Comment: Ah, alright, but I thought it was part of Membership, not Identity? Could you explain that?